# Use Html.DisplayNameFor with IEnumerable<IGrouping>

Tags: c#, linq, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I switched from displaying a table of values (`IEnumerable<FooViewModel>`) to displaying a grouped, table of values (`IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, FooViewModel>>`) in a Razor page.

The syntax to get the display name of the model's property was `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)`.

I don't think I have the correct syntax for using `DisplayNameFor` with `IGrouping<DateTime, FooViewModel>`, as it only displays one of the model's properties (the `ID`, in this case):  `@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.FirstOrDefault().ElementAtOrDefault(0).ID)`.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: How can you use `FirstOrDefault` and `ElementAtOrDefault`? Doesn't `DisplayNameFor` always display only one property's DisplayName? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Your question is unclear. "it only displays one of the model's properties" - Yeah, that's what it does. You can't use `DisplayNameFor` at a model level to somehow render the names of all the properties. That's not how it work.

Comment: I made a mistake--the syntax is correct.  Voted to close.  Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is correct!

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, FooViewModel>>

@if (Model.Any())
{
    /*
     * Since we've checked there are groupings, you can just use .First() to get 
     * the first group.
     *
     * .Key will give you the key you use to group things by. In this case, it's 
     * DateTime.
     *
     * Since there are groupings, there must be elements in the group so it's safe 
     * to use .ElementAt() to get to the view model, FooViewModel.
     */

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Key)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ElementAt(0).ID)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var group in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@group.Key</td>
                    <td>@String.Join(", ", group.Select(x => x.ID))</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

And with the fake data:

```cs
public class FooViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Date time")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Haha ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

var data = new List<FooViewModel>
{
    new FooViewModel { DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 06, 25), ID = 1 },
    new FooViewModel { DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 06, 25), ID = 2 },
    new FooViewModel { DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 06, 24), ID = 3 },
    new FooViewModel { DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 06, 23), ID = 4 }
};
```

It should look like:

[image]

Comment: The `FooViewModel` has additional properties (e.g. `Name`, `StartingDate`) that aren't being displayed.

Comment: @craig: can't you just add more columns with headers like `<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ElementAt(0).Name)</th>`, `<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ElementAt(0).StartingDate)</th>`, etc? Like what @Chris Pratt said, your question is unclear so I just guessed what you looked for.